# Creating bounding box from line using GDAL's ogr2ogr

Tags: qgis, gdal, clip

I am trying to cut a line (.shp, EPSG: 32631) based into a reference line (.shp, EPSG: 32631) [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139964/how-to-use-gdals-ogr2ogr-to-create-bounding-box) using QGIS/GDAL following those comments but I do not know how to solve it.

[enter link description here](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html)

Example code:

```
ogr2ogr -wrapdateline -t_srs EPSG:4326 -clipdst -5 40 15 55 france_4326.shp europe_laea.shp
```

My code (OSGeo4W):

```
ogr2ogr -wrapdateline -clipsrc C:\Users\juavafer\Proyectos\Costas_CoastSat\Output\CMillor\Comparacion\Inputs_Ref\20130612_Ref.shp C:\Users\juavafer\Proyectos\Costas_CoastSat\Output\CMillor\Comparacion\pruebas\Rec_Ext_V2.shp C:\Users\juavafer\Proyectos\Costas_CoastSat\Output\CMillor\Comparacion\Inputs_Sat\CMillor_ldcRefAuto_L8\20130612.shp 20130612 -f "ESRI Shapefile"
```

Errors:
`ERROR 1:GeometrY not of polygon type`
`ERROR 2: cannot load source clip geometry`

Comment: `clipsrc` should be `-clipsrc` and if you pass the `spat_extent` keyword, you also need to pass the `-spat <xmin> <ymin> <xmax> <ymax>` argument according to the docs.

Comment: I see, Can I pass `-spat <xmin> <ymin> <xmax> <ymax>` as `-spat path_file`? Example: `-spat C:/Users/juavafer/Proyectos/Costas_CoastSat/Output/CMillor/Comparacion/pruebas/Rec_Ext.shp`

Comment: Still errors. Code: `ogr2ogr -wrapdateline -clipsrc C:\Users\...\Comparacion\Inputs_Ref\20130612_Ref.shp C:\Users\...Inputs_Ref\20130612_Ref.shp C:\Users\...\pruebas\Rec_Ext_V2.shp C:\Users\....\CMillor_ldcRefAuto_L8\20130612.shp 20130612 -f "ESRI Shapefile"`  Where: 20130612_Ref.shp (line); Clip or extension reference layer, Rec_Ext_V2.shp (line); Output (line clipped) and 20130612.shp (line); line to be clipped

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to pass `-clipsrc xmin ymin xmax ymax` but instead pass a `datasource`, the clip datasource needs to be a polygon.  However, you can generate a polygon bounding box on-the-fly from your line shapefile using SQL.

E.g.

```
ogr2ogr -sql "select Extent(geometry) from test_clip" -dialect SQLite test_bbox.shp test_clip.shp
ogr2ogr -clipsrc test_bbox.shp test_clipped.shp test_input.shp
```

And you can even do it in one line without an intermediate file by using the `/vsistdin/` and `/vsistdout/` virtual files:

```
ogr2ogr -sql "select Extent(geometry) from test_clip" -dialect SQLite -f GeoJSON /vsistdout/ test_clip.shp | ogr2ogr -clipsrc /vsistdin/ test_clipped.shp test_input.shp
```

[image]